# Parts of code not executing in async JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await, es6-promise

I have mentioned the lines that are not running in the comments

This function is a controller for express-framework

```
  uploadStudentData: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { orgid } = req.params;
      const filepath = `../tmp/${req.file.filename}`
      console.log(filepath) // not showing in console
      const requiredOrg = await Organisation.find({
        "admins.email": req.user.email,
        _id: orgid,
      });
      if (!requiredOrg) {
        return res
          .status(400)
          .json({ msg: "You are not part of the organisation" });
      }
      uploadStudentToDB(filepath, requiredOrg) // not running
      return res.status(200).json({ msg: "success" });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      return res.status(500).json({ msg: err.message });
    }
  }
```

### Main goal:

is to run the `uploadStudentToDB()`

If any more details is needed please tell in comments

Comment: And is `requiredOrg` found? Because if not, then you hit an early return.

Comment: Assuming this function is actually being called, I can only assume an error is being thrown and the code therefore entering the `catch` block. Have you tried putting a breakpoint or `console.log` in there?

Comment: @mbojko that's true but the first of the "not running" lines is well above the early return.

Comment: there is no error appearing in console...

Comment: @DronBhattacharya there wouldn't be an error appearing in the console because you are `catch`ing it and not logging or rethrowing it.

Comment: My second guess will be `req.file` being null/undefined.

Comment: I added a console.log just now, but no err still

Comment: how will I know if the req.file is null/undefined. Because `console.log()` not working

Comment: How about `console.log(req)` in the first line?

Comment: @mbojko not working....

Comment: What is the HTTP status code of the response ?

Comment: If a console.log in the first line is "not working", then the function itself wasn't called, and that should be solved first.

Comment: I think this is a async problem... so any help regarding restructuring or chnaging something?

Comment: I am checking once, in other places of the source code

Comment: Try putting `console.log("uploadStudentData called")` at the top of the function and log the values of `req.params`, `orgid`  and `req.file` as early as possible. - or use a debugger to fiind where execution got to before failing and/ or whether data values are what you expected. Either  `console.log` has been disabled somehow, or the line is not being executed, or perhaps the function is not being called.